# Is an acid strong when its conjugate base is strong or weak?

Tags: acid-base

It is often said that stronger acids have weak conjugate bases and vice versa. Yet also in organic chemistry if an acid is proven to have a stable conjugate base it is said to dissociate more, which means it is stronger. Aren't these contradictory statements? What exactly should a strong acid have- a strong or a weak conjugate base?

Comment: `if an acid is proven to have a stable conjugate base it is said to dissociate more, which means it is stronger` This is wrong.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj but many sources say so.. like in this website under Acidity it says so http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch01/ch1-8.html

Comment: @AvnishKabaj What don't you like about that statement?

Comment: Why are these two statements contradictory? If you have a stable conjugate base, then the base is weaker.

Comment: @Zhe I agree that acids with stable conjugate bases are stronger but over here I think that the op is interpreting that statement as "stronger acids have stronger conjugate bases". That's why I said that the statement is wrong.

Comment: @Hema Your statements don't contradict. A stable conjugate base implies a weak conjugate base. If it is stable, it means it is not as prone to grabbing a proton as an unstable base would be.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj So apparently the issue with this quotation is "it." What is "it?" If "it" is the acid, the statement is correct. If "it" is base, the statement is not.

Comment: @Zhe I think so

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathrm{pK_a+pK_b=14}$ and strong acids are defined as dissociating completely in water, then a strong acid must be stronger than hydronium, meaning its $\mathrm{pK_a<-1.74}$. For its conjugate base then, this means $\mathrm{pK_b>15.74}$. So yes, a strong acid and a weak conjugate base are two sides of the same coin.